# Clojurescript repl trying to invoke Clojure function from the Transit library

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I have both the `cognitect.transit-clj` and `cognitect.transit-cljs` dependencies because my project is Clojure on the backend and CLJS on the frontend.  I'm connecting to a shadow-cljs repl in cider with `cider-connect`.

In the repl, I do:

```
(require '[cognitect.transit :as xit])
(def my-writer (xit/writer :json))
```

I get this error:

```
Execution error (ArityException) at nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate$fn (interruptible_eval.clj:91).
Wrong number of args (1) passed to: cognitect.transit/writer
```

It appears that it's trying to invoke the java version of `transmit/writer`.  Is something wrong with my dependencies or setup?

Here's the full stack trace:

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: Syntax error macroexpanding at (NO_SOURCE_FILE:45:29).
#:clojure.error{:phase :execution, :line 45, :column 29, :source "NO_SOURCE_FILE"}
 at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval (Compiler.java:3707)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr.eval (Compiler.java:457)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7182)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7132)
    clojure.core$eval.invokeStatic (core.clj:3214)
    clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:3210)
    nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__42793.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:91)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9086$fn__9089.invoke (main.clj:437)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9086.invoke (main.clj:437)
    clojure.main$repl$fn__9095.invoke (main.clj:458)
    clojure.main$repl.invokeStatic (main.clj:458)
    clojure.main$repl.doInvoke (main.clj:368)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1523)
    nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invokeStatic (interruptible_eval.clj:84)
    nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__42819$fn__42823.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:155)
    clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
    nrepl.middleware.session$session_exec$main_loop__43068$fn__43072.invoke (session.clj:190)
    nrepl.middleware.session$session_exec$main_loop__43068.invoke (session.clj:189)
    clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
Caused by: clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1) passed to: cognitect.transit/writer
 at clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
    clojure.lang.AFn.invoke (AFn.java:32)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo (AFn.java:144)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.eval (Compiler.java:3702)
    clojure.lang.Compiler$DefExpr.eval (Compiler.java:457)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7182)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7132)
    clojure.core$eval.invokeStatic (core.clj:3214)
    clojure.core$eval.invoke (core.clj:3210)
    nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__42793.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:91)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9086$fn__9089.invoke (main.clj:437)
    clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__9086.invoke (main.clj:437)
    clojure.main$repl$fn__9095.invoke (main.clj:458)
    clojure.main$repl.invokeStatic (main.clj:458)
    clojure.main$repl.doInvoke (main.clj:368)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:1523)
    nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invokeStatic (interruptible_eval.clj:84)
    nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:56)
    nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__42819$fn__42823.invoke (interruptible_eval.clj:155)
    clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
    nrepl.middleware.session$session_exec$main_loop__43068$fn__43072.invoke (session.clj:190)
    nrepl.middleware.session$session_exec$main_loop__43068.invoke (session.clj:189)
    clojure.lang.AFn.run (AFn.java:22)
    java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know enough about `cider-connect` but it is very likely that you are just connected to the CLJ REPL and not the actual CLJS REPL you are looking for. A connection always starts out as CLJ and your editor has to "upgrade" it to CLJS. Maybe [this](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#cider) is still current?

For plain shadow-cljs you get to the CLJS REPL directly via `shadow-cljs cljs-repl app` (assuming `:app` is your build id). For nREPL your editor is in control. I'm sure there is a command for that.

Comment: Thanks, you clued me into this... It turns out that the cause was that I had not run this `(shadow/repl :main)` after I connected to the repl.

Comment: Just FYI, `cider-connect` asks for the host and port, so to connect the repl to shadow-cljs, I enter 'locahost' and the nrepl port output from `$ npx shadow-cljs server`.  I think I got all the steps for connecting to the shadow-cljs repl from the fulcro docs, or from various places as I was setting up the project.